# groupby sum() is not adding up but showing weird results

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I have a dataset that I am trying to aggregate by userID. I need to calculate the sum of orders by each user.

```
ID  ORDER
abc 1
bcd 1
ced 1
dfd 1
bcd 1
ced 1
bcd 1
bcd 1
```

This is the dataset

This is the code I used

```
TotalOrders=PL_training.groupby('ID').GR_ORDERS.sum().reset_index()
TotalOrders.columns=['ID','TotalOrders']
```

Instead of adding up the code just accumulates the values to a single row. I know that sum function adds up but not sure why this is not working. Surprisingly, I used the same code to add up other column and is working perfectly fine.

The result is

```
abc 1
bcd 1111
ced 11
dfd 1
```

Expected result

```
abc 1
bcd 4
ced 2
dfd 1
```

Please help me understand what is going wrong. Thanks

Comment: Are sure that the vales are not int but string? `str(1)+str(1)` is converted in `str(11)` in python. Typecast to `int` and try again the `groupby`.

Comment: It is coming as dtype('O') @Orenshi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`Series.astype`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.astype.html) to covert to `int` **before groupby and sum**:

```
new_df=df.copy()
new_df['ORDER']=new_df['ORDER'].astype(int)
new_df.groupby('ID')['ORDER'].sum()
```

or

```
df.groupby('ID')['ORDER'].apply(lambda x: x.astype(int).sum())
```

---

```
ID
abc    1
bcd    4
ced    2
dfd    1
Name: ORDER, dtype: int64
```

Comment: I wouldn't bother with the second option. The first uses a cython implementation of `GroupBy.sum` so it's extremely fast and scaleable. The second uses a `lambda`, which falls back to a very slow python loop and is going to scale horribly as the number of groups becomes large.